# Sort -u Function Command Not Working

Tags: text-processing, sort

***As you can see in the picture attached***
[screen shot](http://ow.ly/I/X7KY)

After I used the sort command to sort a VERY large wordlist file I then split them up using the Split command. From there I confirmed that the listed words are in  a-z order.

I then ran the `sort -u` command and noticed that it was not removing unique words. (It was removing some as I could see the files were a little smaller, but not all.)

What am I doing wrong?

Overall goal: my over all goal is to take all my wordlists and put them into one large file (25gig), then sort and remove any unique words (cutting this by 40% or so) and then split up the files into manageable sizes.  No Windows programs or Linux commands worked.

Comment: Copy and paste output instead of posting screenshots.  Text is much easier to deal with than images, especially when your question has nothing to do with graphics.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no invisible characters at the end of the words?  Like spaces.

Answer (score 4):

sort -u removes unique *lines*. So, the a potential problem is that these three lines are not the same, and `sort -u` will leave all of them:

```
foo
foo 
foo
```

No matter how closely you look, its hard to notice why. That is, unless you take a hex dump, with `xxd` for example:

```
0000000: 666f 6f0a 666f 6f20 0a66 6f6f e280 820a  foo.foo .foo....
```

`0x0a` is newline, if you're not familiar with hex dumps. So the three "foo"s are:

```
666f 6f         0a
666f 6f20       0a
666f 6fe2 8082  0a
```

Aha! That's actually `foo`, `foo<SPACE>` (the `0x20`), and `foo<EN-SPACE>` (the `0xe28082`, which is U+2002 encoded in UTF-8).

You've probably got something similar going on. You need to use a hex editor, or a text editor set to show invisible characters. For example, here is what it looks like in `gvim` with `:set list`. I've just typed in the `ga` command to see what the character under the cursor is, revealing that its U+2002. You can also see how the end of line (`$`) isn't where you expect on the two with spaces after them:

[image: screenshot of gvim demonstrating :set list]

Comment: well this is what i thought too... so i loaded it in a text editor and saw nothing (checking so see if there were spaces). HOWEVER, i did NOT turn on show hidden characters.

so heres the followup question.... is there any script that would delete these after the word? I dont know how to intelligently ask that question however you understand my overall goal. Any suggestion would be great. :( I really want to make this the most efficient wordlist for running through audits.

Comment: @Alex I'm unsure from your comment, when you tried it with show hidden characters (or even better, a hex editor) did it become clear what is going on?

Comment: ^ sorry, had to edit the comment. it submitted and cut me off

Comment: @Alex I think you could do that fairly easily with sed or perl. For example, piping through `perl -p -e 's/\s+$//'`

Comment: @Alex also, you'd ask that as "trimming whitespace from the end of each line" or similar. Also, as a final note, if you're doing matches against this huge wordlist, and need it to be efficient, there are algorithms for that. Probably a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Cheers, i might just go there. I wish i knew how to program. It would be nice to make a script.